# Excel, query: How to add specific info from query 2 into query 1 with lookup

Tags: excel, lookup, excelquery

I want to add data from the second query (Data) to the first query (Overview) depending on the information in the first query. I'll show my question with pictures to make it more clear. I have these two queries:

[image: Overview]

[image: Data]

I want to add the "ITEM" information from the Data query to overview query looking up the "NAME.1" Column. I think I'm close to the solution because I can lookup the row with this formula:

```
=Data{[NAME.1=[NAME.1]]}
```

[image: Lookup]

What do I need to add to the formula to only show the column "ITEM"? (and/or to show column number 0 in this case. Both solutions would be nice to understand it better how it works)

---

The data used in my screenshots:

**Overview**

| NAME.1 | NUMBER | RANDOM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | 243324 | qwsa |
| Name2 | 6747 | dsfsdf |
| Name3 | 455 | yyu |
| Name4 | 908098 | hfhn |
| Name5 | 34 | ertew |
| Name6 | 132 | uil |
| Name7 | 64 | tgvc |
| Name8 | 876 | iorts |

**Data**

| ITEM | Y/N | NAME.1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123123 | Y | Name5 |
| 234324 | Y | Name1 |
| 345345 | N | Name7 |
| 456456 | Y | Name2 |
| 567567 | N | Name8 |
| 678678 | N | Name3 |
| 789789 | Y | Name6 |
| 890890 | N | Name4 |

---

---

**Some extra information in reply to the answer of Darren below**

When using merge, is it also possible to to merge the ITEM information if NAME.1=NAME.1 and if there is no NAME.1 match, to look if there is a match in NAME.2=NAME.2? Possibly with the result in the same column.

**Overview**

[image: Overview2]

| NAME.1 | NAME.2 | NUMBER | RANDOM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 |  | 243324 | qwsa |
|  | Name2 | 6747 | dsfsdf |
| Name3 |  | 455 | yyu |
| Name4 |  | 908098 | hfhn |
|  | Name5 | 34 | ertew |
|  | Name6 | 132 | uil |
| Name7 |  | 64 | tgvc |
| Name8 |  | 876 | iorts |

**Data**

[image: Data2]

| ITEM | Y/N | NAME.1 | NAME.2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123123 | Y |  | Name5 |
| 234324 | Y | Name1 |  |
| 345345 | N | Name7 |  |
| 456456 | Y |  | Name2 |
| 567567 | N | Name8 |  |
| 678678 | N | Name3 |  |
| 789789 | Y |  | Name6 |
| 890890 | N | Name4 |  |

---

---

**Some extra information in reply to the answer of Ron below**

When I use `=try Data{[NAME.1=[NAME.1]]}[ITEM] otherwise Data{[NAME.2=[NAME.2]]}[ITEM])` and my tables look like this:

**Overview**

[image: Overview3]

| NAME.1 | NAME.2 | NUMBER | RANDOM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name11 |  | 243324 | qwsa |
|  | Name22 | 6747 | dsfsdf |
| Name13 |  | 455 | yyu |
| Name14 |  | 908098 | hfhn |
|  | Name25 | 34 | ertew |
|  |  | 132 | uil |
|  |  | 64 | tgvc |
| Name18 |  | 876 | iorts |

**Data**

[image: Data3]

| ITEM | Y/N | NAME.1 | NAME.2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123123 | Y |  | Name25 |
| 234324 | Y | Name11 |  |
| 345345 | N | Name17 |  |
| 456456 | Y | Name12 | Name22 |
| 567567 | N | Name18 |  |
| 678678 | N | Name13 |  |
| 789789 | Y | Name16 |  |
| 890890 | N | Name14 |  |

Then I will get the wrong information in the table:

[image: OverviewWrong]

The green highlighted is correct, the 3 yellow ones are wrong and should be null. I think I should add some kind of if null=null give null or something in that direction?

---

---

**Some extra information in reply to the suggestion of Ron below**

When I do merge I get this code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Name] = "Table1")),
    #"Expanded Content" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Content", {"NAME", "NAME.2", "NUMBER", "RANDOM"}, {"NAME.1", "NAME.2", "NUMBER", "RANDOM"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Content", "AddInfoFromTable", each try Data{[NAME.1=[NAME.1]]}[ITEM] otherwise Data{[NAME.2=[NAME.2]]}[ITEM]),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Custom", {"NAME.1"}, Data, {"NAME.1"}, "Data", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Data", {"ITEM"}, {"ITEM"})
in
    #"Expanded Data"
```

And modify the code in "Advanced Editor" to this, it still shows no error

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Name] = "Table1")),
    #"Expanded Content" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Content", {"NAME", "NAME.2", "NUMBER", "RANDOM"}, {"NAME.1", "NAME.2", "NUMBER", "RANDOM"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Content", "AddInfoFromTable", each try Data{[NAME.1=[NAME.1]]}[ITEM] otherwise Data{[NAME.2=[NAME.2]]}[ITEM]),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Custom", {"NAME.1","NAME.2"}, Data, {"NAME.1","NAME.2"}, "Data", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Data", {"ITEM"}, {"ITEM"})
in
    #"Expanded Data"`
```

However, I'm not sure what to do with these values in your suggestions:

```
{"ITEM", each [ITEM]{0}, Int64.Type})
in
    Join
```

In my example the data in ITEM is numbers, in reality it contains a combination of numbers and letters (e.g., 0AB123 or AB123, etc.)

Comment: Please **edit** your question to include your **data as text** which can be copy/pasted.  As a screenshot It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet. One can try an OCR program, or manually enter it. Having to do either of these is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I've added the data as text to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the most efficient method is using the `Table.Join` function as demonstrated in another answer:

```
let

//Read in the two tables
    SourceOverview = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Overview"]}[Content],
    Overview = Table.TransformColumnTypes(SourceOverview,{{"NAME", type text}, {"NUMBER", Int64.Type}, {"RANDOM", type text}}),

    SourceData = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Data"]}[Content],
    Data = Table.TransformColumnTypes(SourceData,{{"NAME", type text}, {"ITEM", Int64.Type}, {"Y/N", type text}}),

//Join the two tables using Name as common element
//and extract the ITEM column
    Joined = Table.TransformColumns(
        Table.NestedJoin(Overview,"NAME",Data,"NAME","ITEM", JoinKind.RightOuter),
        {"ITEM", each [ITEM]{0}, Int64.Type}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(Joined,{{"NAME", Order.Ascending}})
    
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

However, your method can also work the way you want by merely adding the `Field Name` to your formula:

```
Data{[NAME=[NAME]]}[ITEM]
```

Your posted data for this problem:
***Overview***
[image]

***Data***
[image]

***Results***
[image]

***Edit:** Given your additional information of having to compare Name.1 or Name.2, you can modify the `Table.Join` function as follows:*

*Please note that this method requires that `NAME.1` or `NAME.2` be *`null`*. If that is not the case, then coding would be more complex*

```
   Join = Table.TransformColumns(    
        Table.NestedJoin(Overview,{"NAME.1","NAME.2"},Data2,{"NAME.1","NAME.2"},"ITEM",JoinKind.FullOuter),
        {"ITEM", each [ITEM]{0}, Int64.Type})
in
    Join
```

***Edit2:** Now with further information that either table might or might not have Names in none, one or both NAME.1 and NAME.2 cells, the following shows two different techniques of managing that situation which probably gives the results you want*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Overview3"]}[Content],
    #"Overview" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"NAME.1", type text}, {"NAME.2", type text}, {"NUMBER", Int64.Type}, {"RANDOM", type text}}),
  
//Add index column to be able to go back to original table order
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Overview, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),

//Create a Name column that we will expand to all names in a single column
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Name", each List.RemoveNulls({[NAME.1]} & {[NAME.2]})),
    #"Expanded Name" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Name"),

//Since Data table could also have Names in both NAME columns, we can unpivot (and delete the unneeded columns)
    #"Unpivot Data" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Table.RemoveColumns(Data3,"Y/N"),{"ITEM"},"Attribute","Name"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivot Data",{"Attribute"}),

//Now we can merge the tables and return the ITEM
    #"Add Item" = Table.TransformColumns(
        Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded Name","Name",#"Removed Columns","Name","ITEM",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
        {"ITEM", each try [ITEM]{0} otherwise null, type text}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Add Item",{"Name"}),

//Group by Index to return initial table in order
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns1", {"Index"}, {

    //If two names in the same row of Overview have different ITEMs, we will returned a concatenated string
        {"All", each  Table.Distinct(Table.TransformColumns(_, {"ITEM", (c)=>Text.Combine(_[ITEM], ", ")}))  , 
        type table [NAME.1=nullable text, NAME.2=nullable text, NUMBER=nullable number, RANDOM=nullable text, Index=number, ITEM=text]}}),


    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Index"}),
    #"Expanded All" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns2", "All", {"NAME.1", "NAME.2", "NUMBER", "RANDOM", "Index", "ITEM"}),
    #"Removed Columns3" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded All",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns3"
```

Comment: Thank you! That works. I've added an additional question to the end of my original question. What if I have 2 columns which I want to check. If NAME.1 has no match, that it will check if NAME.2 has a match and add it to the column together. Is that possible?

Comment: @MMM Sure, just check for an error: `(try Data2{[NAME.1=[NAME.1]]} otherwise Data2{[NAME.2=[NAME.1]]})[ITEM]`

Comment: Thank you! Using `try Data{[NAME.1=[NAME.1]]}[ITEM] otherwise Data{[NAME.2=[NAME.2]]}[ITEM])` works! For completeness, is it also possible to use this within the merge method?

Comment: @MMM I would prefer the merge method as it would be both more efficient. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I've added additional information to my main question with screenshots/data. I noticed when the Overview data is null in NAME.1 and has a match in NAME.2, it still matches NAME.1=NAME.1=null even if NAME.2=NAME.2 has a match. I'm not sure if my explanation is clear, hopefully the screenshots help. (I'm sorry that I'm extending my question further and further. If this is not allowed, please let me know)

Comment: @MMM since you might have entries in both name columns, I would use a different approach- creating a single name column for each table and then doing a merge. I will post that later today.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated for the help. I'm not sure how to respond to your suggestion, because of the limited information I can add in this comment. I have added another piece of comment in the end of my question. (I don't have enough reputation to start a chat. I'm not sure if that would be the better way to do so)

Comment: @MMM It is bad form to keep extending your question. You should post a comprehensive data set intially. But I'll respond to this one if it is complete. In your last example, you only have names in both `NAME.1` and `NAME.2` columns for your **`Data`** table. What about your **`Overview`** table?

Comment: You mean the data in these two tables? [Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxFnX.png)  [Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFPBp.png) I want the query to be able to handle incomplete information. So, "Overview" gets additional information from "Data" to add in a new column (in "Overview"). However, if no NAME.1 or NAME.2 information is available in "Overview" (or if it doesn't match the information in "Data") then it should output nothing (null)

Comment: @MMM No I mean in the Overview table, could you have Names in both columns, like you do in the Data table.

Comment: The Data table can have NAME.1, NAME.2 or NAME.1&NAME.2. And the Overview table can have NAME.1, NAME.2, NAME.1&NAME.2 or nothing.

Comment: @MMM OK, the final edit should do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Is it possible to share your file with me? I think I have somewhere a minor mistake, what causes it to not work for me. If I can have a look in your working file, I can compare what the differences are.

Comment: @MMM Take a look at this [Book1.xlsx Query: Overview3](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Aml6o6HIc9uOynDHPdAi7qv2pnT0?e=UbXSFT). It's probably the one on the last sheet and matches with the tables named `Overview3` and `Data3`. Let me know.

Comment: Question about this part: `#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns1", {"Index"}, {
        {"All", each  Table.Distinct(Table.TransformColumns(_, {"ITEM", (c)=>Text.Combine(_[ITEM], ", ")}))  , 
        type table [NAME.1=nullable text, NAME.2=nullable text, NUMBER=nullable number, RANDOM=nullable text, Index=number, ITEM=text]}}),`
Do I need to mention all the columns (NAME.1, NAME.2, RANDOM, etc.)? Because in the actual file I want to apply this to has a lot of columns. And also combining text, date, (whole)numbers, etc. And some column names have spaces. (e.g., "RANDOM TEXT")

Comment: And the same for `    #"Expanded All" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns2", "All", {"NAME.1", "NAME.2", "NUMBER", "RANDOM", "Index", "ITEM"}),`. I want to expand all columns

Comment: @MMM `#"Grouped Rows"`: At some point you need to set the data types and mention all the columns. You don't need to do this here. You could do it in a stand-alone step.  You could ignore setting the type it but that might have unforeseen consequences `#"Expanded All"`: You do need to list all of the columns that you wish to expand. In both cases the column lists can be generated dynamically. There are examples of the techniques used in other questions here. If you can't figure out how to apply it to your situation, post a new question with sufficient details.

Comment: Thank you Ron. I made a new topic with hopefully better information about my new question to add multiple columns on an efficient/clean way. It can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77760115/excel-power-query-add-multiple-columns-from-query2-into-query1

Answer (score 1):

You should merge the two queries based on the *Name.1* field.

On the **Home** tab select **Merge Queries**.
You'll get a dialog box with the the first table already selected.  Select the second table in the lower half of the dialog box and then click the *Name.1* header on each table.
[image]

Click OK and then expand your combined table.
[image]

Select which fields you want to show from the Data table and whether to include the original column name as a prefix and press OK.

The `M` code will look something like this:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Overview"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"NAME.1", type text}, {"NUMBER", Int64.Type}, {"RANDOM", type any}, {"Name", type text}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type", {"NAME.1"}, Data, {"NAME.1"}, "Data", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Data", {"ITEM", "Y/N", "NAME.1", "Name"}, {"Data.ITEM", "Data.Y/N", "Data.NAME.1", "Data.Name"})
in
    #"Expanded Data"
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. However, is it also possible on the way I tried to do it? (=Data{[NAME.1=[NAME.1]]}) I'm trying to learn how these queries work and I think it may help if I understand how to do it with the formula. How to show 1 cell instead of a record.

Comment: when using merge, is it also possible to to merge the ITEM information if NAME.1=NAME.1 and if there is no NAME.1 match, to look if there is a match in NAME.2=NAME.2? Possibly with the result in the same column. I will add screenshots of the example in my question. I don't think I can add it in my comment here (relatively new to this site)